# How to avoid exception because of some missing Xml Elemets (e.g Description & Image) when deserialising Xml to C# Object

Tags: c#, xml, deserialization, nullreferenceexception

My Xml Looks as following:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SearchSuggestion xmlns="http://opensearch.org/searchsuggest2" version="2.0">
   <Query xml:space="preserve">middle ages</Query>
   <Section>
      <Item>
         <Text xml:space="preserve">Middle Ages</Text>
         <Url xml:space="preserve">https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Middle_Ages</Url>
         <Description xml:space="preserve">In the history of Europe, the Middle Ages or medieval period lasted from the 5th to the 15th century. It began with the fall of the Western Roman Empire and merged into the Renaissance and the Age of Discovery.</Description>
         <Image source="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/0a/JuengeresMathildenkreuz.jpg/35px-JuengeresMathildenkreuz.jpg" width="35" height="50" />
      </Item>
      <Item>
         <Text xml:space="preserve">Middle Ages in film</Text>
         <Url xml:space="preserve">https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Middle_Ages_in_film</Url>
         <Description xml:space="preserve">Medieval films imagine and portray the Middle Ages through the visual, audio and thematic forms of cinema.</Description>
         <Image source="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/39/Fairbanks_Robin_Hood_standing_by_wall_w_sword.jpg/40px-Fairbanks_Robin_Hood_standing_by_wall_w_sword.jpg" width="40" height="50" />
      </Item>
      <Item>
         <Text xml:space="preserve">Talk:Middle Ages/GA1</Text>
         <Url xml:space="preserve">https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk:Middle_Ages/GA1</Url>
      </Item>
      <Item>
         <Text xml:space="preserve">Talk:Middle Ages/Archive 4</Text>
         <Url xml:space="preserve">https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk:Middle_Ages/Archive_4</Url>
      </Item>
   </Section>
</SearchSuggestion>
```

My Object looks as following:

```
[XmlRoot("SearchSuggestion", Namespace = "http://opensearch.org/searchsuggest2")]
    public class SearchItem
    {
        [XmlElement("Query")]
        public string query { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("Section")]
        public Section section { get; set; }

    }
    public class Section
    {
        [XmlElement("Item")]
        public Item[] items { get; set; }
    }
    public class Item
    {
        [XmlElement("Text")]
        public string Text { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("Url")]
        public string Url { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("Description")]
        public string Description { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("Image")]
        public Image Image { get; set; }
    }
    public class Image
    {
        [XmlAttribute("source")]
        public string source { get; set; }
    }
```

My Controller looks as following:

```
        string wikiResponse; //raw response from REST endpoint
        SearchItem wikiXmlResponse = null; //Deserialized response


        wikiResponse = await httpClient.GetStringAsync(queryUri);
        var buffer = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(wikiResponse);
        using (var stream = new MemoryStream(buffer)) {

        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(SearchItem));
        wikiXmlResponse = (SearchItem)serializer.Deserialize(stream);
       }
        Items [] infoResult = wikiXmlResponse.section.items;
        for (int i = 0; i < infoResultCount; i++)
            {
               Title = infoResult[i].Text;
               Explaination = infoResult[i].Description;
               Image_Url = infoResult[i].Image.source; 
               Article_Url = infoResult[i].Url; 
            }
```

The Xml response I get from wikipedia Api and some times in response some elements e.g. Description and Image are missing. What is the best way to avoid exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no exceptions caused by missing elements (see [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/CY6kgh)).

The exception in this case will be a null reference exception because you're attempting to read `source` from a `null` `Image` property. You need to handle this:

```
Image_Url = infoResult[i].Image?.source;
```

Comment: Yea, it works 
Thanks